# Ember route-action is not a helper error

Tags: ember.js

I have looked at one other question like this and couldn't find the solution. I am trying to complete a simple tutorial to create a reading list however i get the error (as stated in the title).

Here is my application route:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';
import db from '../utils/db';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    return db.books();
  },

  actions: {

    addBook(book) {
      db.addBook(book);
      this.refresh();
    }

  }

});
```

Here is my reading list component:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  title: "",

  actions: {

    onEnter() {
      const title = this.get('title');
      if (title) {
        this.get('addBook')({ title });
      }
      this.set('title', "");  // reset title
    }

  }

});
```

Here is my application template:

```html
<h1>Reading list</h1>

{{reading-list books=model addBook=(route-action "addBook")}}

{{outlet}}
```

And here is my reading list template:

```html
{{one-way-input
  title
  update=(action (mut title))
  keyEvents=(hash
    13=(action 'onEnter')
  )
}}

<ul>
{{#each books as |book|}}
  <li>{{ book.title }}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

I have installed the addons:
ember install ember-one-way-controls
ember install ember-route-action-helper

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I am a complete beginner with ember.

I am grabbing some data from an array in a db.js file.

Comment: Did you do an "npm install" or an "ember install" for the `ember-route-action-helper`?  Cause otherwise, it should be working.

Comment: really simple, i was used to react live reloading I forgot to restart the server after installing the addon..

Comment: Thank you for the update!  I’m voting to close the question as typo/can not reproduce

Comment: Did you restarted the `ember serve` process after installing new dependencies?

Comment: Yeah, this happened to me. A simple server restart fixed @R.Thompson